# Why is Vim ignoring &diff?

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc` I have a function:

```
function! SetPHPOptions()
  setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab
  if !&diff
    call tagbar#autoopen(0)
  endif
endfunction
```

This is called with:

```
autocmd FileType php call SetPHPOptions()
```

But when I run `vimdiff file1.php file2.php`, Tagbar is opening. When I comment out that line, it doesn't.

I changed the function to this:

```
function! SetPHPOptions()
  setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab
  echo "Outside function" &diff
  if !&diff
    call tagbar#autoopen(0)
    echo "Inside function" &diff
  endif
endfunction
```

And in the console as Vim loads it outputs:

```
Outside function 0
Inside function 0
```

As a sanity test, I ran `echo &diff` in `vimdiff` and it returns `1`.

**What is causing Vim to ignore that value of `&diff` in my use-case and is there a workaround?**

Comment: Because `filetype` is local to buffer, but `diff` is local to window.

Comment: Would there be a way to do what I want?

Comment: When echoing message for debugging purpose, prefer `echom` which writes a message. You can see the message list with `:mes`. For your case, you will see that it first echoes `Outside function 1` on first buffer, than the `&diff` option becomes 0.